# git - Push to all branch but only have same code? with follow up question

Tags: git, performance, git-branch

Did git can push to all branch but Only have same code? I mean if i have 3 branch like ver_light, ver_medium, and ver_heavy.

```
= ver_light
\controller\a
\controller\b
```

```
= ver_medium
\controller\a
\controller\b
\controller\c
\controller\d
```

Fisrt, i change ver_medium in controller **A** and **C**. How i do in git without git push controller c in ver_light branch?

Second, this example only 1 or 2 file. How about more than 100+ file? Do i needed select or pickup i need change to ver_light branch?

Third, did git have setup file like : oh, this code only can be push to certain branch and this code can be pushed to all branch ?

**Sorry for my bad english. I got C+ but it wont stop to asking.**

Comment: You can do a `git merge`  to merge one branch into another to make this new branch have the same code. There is no automatic sync between branches whenever you do git push. It involves manually running commands to make them be in sync.

Comment: @nice_dev Thanks for the answer. I think i must try `git merge` with specific file. Gonna google it.

Comment: `git merge` actually merges all the code of all files from one branch to another.

Comment: The `git push` command pushes *commits*, not files. (Commits then *contain* files, but each commit has a full snapshot of *every* file.) Having sent some commits to another Git repository, the last part of `git push` is a request that that other Git repository set one or more of *its* branch name(s) to remember the new commit(s). So you'll need to make at least one commit, and probably at least three commits, and then push those commits and have the other Git repository update all three branch names.

Comment: Sorry for late replay. Thank for answer, i almost get the answer. Currently just temporary, i think im must update on branch with few fiture first (ver_light) then i merge to big one (ver_medium). So branch with few fiture not contaminate with big branch.